# How to Get TFS Field values dynamically?

Tags: c#-4.0

there is a scenario like "I have a field value in TFS which has just been changed by my team member.Can I get the value of that changed field into an application immediately it is changed?".. Pls tell me how to acheive this using C#.net.. thanks in advance

Comment: Presuming you're talking about work items? does/can your application that wants the change have a webservice?

Comment: ya I am talking about the work items. And yes my application can use a webservice

Answer (score 0):

You either want to look into SOAP subscriptions, or writing a tfs server plugin that forwards updates to your app.  I'd probably recommend doing the latter of the two options.

[Team Foundation Server 2010 Event Handling with Subscribers](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers/)

If it is imperative that your application not miss any updates (eg you're writing a sync) the you'll probably want to put a servicebus in as the transport between the plugin and your application.

Alternatively you could go with the polling up update approach, looking at each work items history to see if it has changed. Seems like a lot more work, with no real benefit.

Comment: hi betty.. your answer is helpful.There is a class library named AssignedTohandler. But can you pls explain how to call the ProcessEvent Method in that class.That means how can I populate TeamFoundationRequestContext object with actual work item data.. Pls help..

Comment: you don't call it yourself, you compile your class to an assembly and stick it in the tfs plugin directory. It then calls your plugin (process event method) which then fires off your custom code.